# Apply a function using each element of a data frame as an input to produce a list of data frames

Tags: r, loops

I would like to know how to apply a function I have written to produce a list of data frames `output` containing the results of the function when applied using different elements of `CHANGING_INPUT`.

The function is written as:

```
function1 <- function(x = 1, y, z) {
    output <- ((1 / df1 / scalar1) * scalar2 * -scalar3 * x) + (df2 * (1 - x)) + ((1 / df1 / scalar1) * x * CHANGING_INPUT[y, z])
    output
}
```

Currently, the function takes 3 constants, two 9x4 data frames and another scalar value  which is called from a third data frame `CHANGING_INPUT` using y and z as the row and column index.

`scalar1` `scalar2` and `scalar3` are 5100, 1.8 and 0.9 respectively

`df1` and `df2`  are:

```
structure(list(`2011` = c(0.232760280361466, 0.232760280361466, 
0.232760280361466, 0.232760280361466), `2015` = c(0.237454196065926, 
0.237454196065926, 0.237761576836319, 0.23745419606313), `2020` = c(0.243865255342033, 
0.243865255318483, 0.244731985692455, 0.243865255272293), `2025` = c(0.250576929422025, 
0.250576929505411, 0.252051235357712, 0.250576929459351), `2030` = c(0.257591865482084, 
0.257591865458864, 0.259723510459156, 0.257591865446006), `2035` = c(0.264914318542675, 
0.264914318637383, 0.267755064442473, 0.264914318608059), `2040` = c(0.272550046096461, 
0.272550046127737, 0.276154096131385, 0.272550046096482), `2045` = c(0.280506234929875, 
0.280506234860898, 0.284930672477366, 0.280506234819098), `2050` = c(0.288791456840605, 
0.28879145675613, 0.294096688663525, 0.288791456771391)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("iea6", 
"iea4", "rcp8", "rcp6"))
```

```
structure(list(`2011` = c(0.00014797328112216, 0.00014797328112216, 
0.00014797328112216, 0.00014797328112216), `2015` = c(0.000145048194433412, 
0.000145048194433412, 0.000144860674539145, 0.00014504819443512
), `2020` = c(0.000141234971548911, 0.00014123497156255, 0.000140734780958637, 
0.000141234971589301), `2025` = c(0.00013745200916718, 0.000137452009121439, 
0.000136648020594382, 0.000137452009146705), `2030` = c(0.000133708812332024, 
0.000133708812344077, 0.000132611415651631, 0.000133708812350751
), `2035` = c(0.000130012989065563, 0.000130012989019083, 0.000128633616965254, 
0.000130012989033475), `2040` = c(0.000126370561639201, 0.0001263705616247, 
0.000124721316404496, 0.000126370561639191), `2045` = c(0.000122786227581039, 
0.000122786227611232, 0.000120879588359291, 0.000122786227629529
), `2050` = c(0.00011926357786619, 0.000119263577901076, 0.000117112173402963, 
0.000119263577894774)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("iea6", 
"iea4", "rcp8", "rcp6"))
```

`CHANGING_INPUT` looks like this:

```
structure(list(low = c(0.423, 0.527, 0.714, 0.432, 0.4, 0.492, 
0.548, 0.706, 0.428, 0.612, 0.329, 0.368, 0.399, 0.26, 0.295, 
0.9, 1.044), mean = c(0.682, 0.805, 1.082, 0.736, 0.664, 1.382, 
0.924, 1.34, 0.847, 1.061, 0.46, 0.525, 0.546, 0.373, 0.429, 
1.371, 1.729), high = c(1.05, 1.155, 1.532, 1.159, 1.059, 2.615, 
1.494, 2.769, 1.75, 1.699, 0.62, 0.724, 0.715, 0.499, 0.577, 
2.009, 2.952)), row.names = c("misc_bra", "misc_chi", "misc_ind", 
"misc_eur", "misc_usa", "swch_bra", "swch_chi", "swch_ind", "swch_eur", 
"swch_usa", "strw_bra", "strw_chi", "strw_ind", "strw_eur", "strw_usa", 
"wsrc_eur", "wsrc_usa"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to loop through each element of `CHANGING_INPUT` to produce a list of 51 data frames. Each element of the list should contain the outputs of the function when applied with each element (all combinations of y and z) of `CHANGING_INPUT`. All other inputs to `function1` should remain the same across all iterations.

I know the answer to this question is likely to be a simple for loop, but I am not sure where to start as I am somewhat of a beginner in R.

Comment: What is `scalar1` (et al)? What type of object is `df1` (matrix or frame)? It would help if you provided ambiguous data, preferable the output of `dput(x)` for each of the variables you're using. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Apologies, I am new to this and this is the first question I have posted. I have followed your advice and edited my question. I hope this makes more sense to you now.

Answer (score 0):

Heres's an option.

First, I'm going to add an attribute to the `output` within `function1` so that within the frame, you know what the starting parameters were. It's not required, but I find it can be easily confusing determining which input conditions resulted in which output.

```r
function1 <- function(x = 1, y, z) {
  output <- ((1 / df1 / scalar1) * scalar2 * -scalar3 * x) +
    (df2 * (1 - x)) +
    ((1 / df1 / scalar1) * x * CHANGING_INPUT[y, z])
  attr(output, "coef") <- list(x=x, y=y, z=z)
  output
}
```

From here, I think you are just iterating over every combination of the `CHANGING_INPUT` column names and row names, so I'll expand it out:

```r
eg <- expand.grid(rownames(CHANGING_INPUT), colnames(CHANGING_INPUT),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
eg[c(1:3, 49:51),]
#        Var1 Var2
# 1  misc_bra  low
# 2  misc_chi  low
# 3  misc_ind  low
# 49 strw_usa high
# 50 wsrc_eur high
# 51 wsrc_usa high
dim(eg)
# [1] 51  2
```

And with this, I'll run it with `Map`:

```r
results <- Map(function1, list(x = 1), eg$Var1, eg$Var2)
results[1:3]
# $x
#              2011          2015          2020          2025          2030          2035          2040          2045          2050
# iea6 -0.001008359 -0.0009884259 -0.0009624408 -0.0009366620 -0.0009111541 -0.0008859690 -0.0008611478 -0.0008367225 -0.0008127175
# iea4 -0.001008359 -0.0009884259 -0.0009624408 -0.0009366620 -0.0009111541 -0.0008859690 -0.0008611478 -0.0008367225 -0.0008127175
# rcp8 -0.001008359 -0.0009871481 -0.0009590323 -0.0009311832 -0.0009036759 -0.0008765693 -0.0008499091 -0.0008237298 -0.0007980569
# rcp6 -0.001008359 -0.0009884259 -0.0009624408 -0.0009366620 -0.0009111541 -0.0008859690 -0.0008611478 -0.0008367225 -0.0008127175
# $<NA>
#               2011          2015          2020          2025          2030          2035          2040          2045          2050
# iea6 -0.0009207487 -0.0009025476 -0.0008788203 -0.0008552812 -0.0008319895 -0.0008089926 -0.0007863280 -0.0007640248 -0.0007421055
# iea4 -0.0009207487 -0.0009025476 -0.0008788203 -0.0008552812 -0.0008319895 -0.0008089926 -0.0007863280 -0.0007640248 -0.0007421055
# rcp8 -0.0009207487 -0.0009013808 -0.0008757079 -0.0008502784 -0.0008251611 -0.0008004096 -0.0007760657 -0.0007521610 -0.0007287186
# rcp6 -0.0009207487 -0.0009025476 -0.0008788203 -0.0008552812 -0.0008319895 -0.0008089926 -0.0007863280 -0.0007640248 -0.0007421055
# $<NA>
#              2011          2015          2020          2025          2030          2035          2040          2045          2050
# iea6 -0.000763219 -0.0007481319 -0.0007284640 -0.0007089522 -0.0006896455 -0.0006705831 -0.0006517961 -0.0006333088 -0.0006151396
# iea4 -0.000763219 -0.0007481319 -0.0007284640 -0.0007089522 -0.0006896455 -0.0006705831 -0.0006517961 -0.0006333088 -0.0006151396
# rcp8 -0.000763219 -0.0007471647 -0.0007258841 -0.0007048053 -0.0006839853 -0.0006634685 -0.0006432896 -0.0006234747 -0.0006040430
# rcp6 -0.000763219 -0.0007481319 -0.0007284640 -0.0007089522 -0.0006896455 -0.0006705831 -0.0006517961 -0.0006333088 -0.0006151396
attr(results[[1]], "coef")
# $x
# [1] 1
# $y
# [1] "misc_bra"
# $z
# [1] "low"
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful response. I really appreciate your help!